# run-as command in android

Tags: android

I am currently developing directly on my device using an ide app called AIDE. But after creating a DB I can't access it to check my data/app are working correctly.

I have managed to get run-as to work using adb with my phone plugged into my laptop, but I'd really like it to work straight off the phone so I can code, test and debug, all whilst on the move.

Using connectbot I can see the run-as command in system/bin/ but it has no executable access.

Any ideas?

Comment: run-as will only work if you are already root or if you connect via adb shell.

Comment: Why will it only work as root? Are you sure its not because without root it doesn't have executable permissions? I can't seem to find any official documentation on it

Comment: `/system/bin/run-as` is executable by [everyone](http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/0755/) on my device but it explicitly checks that it is executed by root or adb shell -> [sourcecode run-as.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/run-as/run-as.c)

Comment: Firstly I was actually trying to ask an individual person this, but have obviously screwed up! haha
Secondly, thanks for your help. But what if I remove that line from the code, will it then let me run it regardless??...

Comment: Russ, I'm not sure how you imagine reinstalling the run-as command after you change the code and recompiling? You need to be root to do that too. If anyone could just replace the executable, the executable checking that it is root would be rather pointless.

Comment: Tobias, I have no idea either, I gave up on that idea a long time ago and just coded on a laptop!